# sitefinity backend page footer is overlap with content

Tags: sitefinity

I have created a backend page to display table of content , as I have set one page fetching 20 items ,hence the content expand to the bottom , but it overlap with the default footer , how to set the footer to be extended downward and not collide with main content .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jaqh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You talking about the "Copyright © 2005-2021 Progress Software Corporation and/or one of its subsidiaries or affiliates. All rights reserved" footer?

What about just outright hiding it with an inline style on your view file?

```
.sfFooter {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this works by hiding , but i think it's better to put the default content there